# If all injections from a set E onto itself $j:E ->E$ are surjective, then E is finite

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For my Mathematical Logic class I need to prove that a set E is finite iff all injections $j:E ->E$ are surjective. I managed to prove the "forward" direction of the proposition, but I'm having a lot of trouble proving the "backward" implication (i.e. all injections are surjective $=>$ E finite).

We're given the following definition of finiteness of a set: A set E is finite if there exists a $n \in \Bbb{N}$ and a bijection $f:E-> \{k \in \Bbb{N} : k<n\}$

And a proposition we can simply assume: If a set E is not finite, then there exists an injection $i:\Bbb{N}->E$

I've tried to find a contradiction assuming that the proposition is true for our set E and I also tried to find a function f so that we have finiteness according to the definition but I don't get anywhere.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Contraposition. If $E$ is infinite, there exists an injection $f:E\rightarrow W$ which is not surjective.

Take $f:\Bbb N_0\rightarrow\Bbb N_0: x \mapsto 2x$.

Comment: thanks, i tried going this way too but I have no clue how to begin constructing such an f